# THREE.DoubleSide doesn't work with THREE.MeshLambertMaterial and custom geometry

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to make a double-sided mesh with `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial`, but only the front side is shaded. It works fine when I use `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`. I am using the `THREE.WebGLRenderer`, version 57.

Here's a simplified example with a rectangle:

```
var rectWidth = 100, rectLength = 100;
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, rectWidth, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(rectLength, rectWidth, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(rectLength, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(0, 1, 2, 3));
// MeshBasicMaterial works
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xCC0000,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
var rect = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(rect);
```

What am I doing wrong? I found http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_performance_doublesided.html, which shows that `THREE.DoubleSide` works with `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` (which also didn't work in my case). The example uses a built-in geometry though, whereas I am building a custom one, so I suppose I am missing something there.

Comment: `MeshBasicMaterial` does not require lights. The other materials you mentioned do.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Any idea why `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial` wouldn't work?

Comment: "Wouldn't work" is not very descriptive. Did you add lights to the scene so as to illuminate both sides of the mesh?